# Push value to jquery array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Simply put, trying to push simple answer **values** to a jquery array.

**HTML**

```
<div class="answer-A">
    <a href="#question2" value="A">
        <p style="color: white;">THOMAS EDISON</p>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="answer-B">
    <a href="#question2" value="B">
        <p style="color: white;">ALBERT EINSTEIN</p>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="answer-C">
    <a href="#question2" value="C">
        <p style="color: white;">NELSON MANDELA</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
var finalAnswers = [''];

$(document).ready(function () {
     $('.answer-A').finalAnswers.push();
     console.log(finalAnswers);
});
```

Probably shouldn't be using value - there's probably a much easier way?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: result of `$()` does not have an array called `finalAnswers` just because you've created a global called `finalAnswers` - that's not how javascript works, and jQuery "array" is a javascript array, there's no distinction

Comment: @erayner, multiple elements are in NodeList not array

Comment: Broken code is not a good substitute for a complete and proper explanation...see [ask]

Comment: trying to achieve an array that has values in it depending on which <a href=""> user clicks. End array should be something like finalsAnswers =  ['A','B','A','A','C']

Comment: *"depending on what button..."* There are no buttons shown and nothing like that is mentioned in the question. Provide a proper and detailed explanation of what exactly it is you are trying to accomplish. How many times do people have to ask this?

Comment: sorry, it's pretty hard to explain what I am trying to do without tripping over myself. essentially, user clicks on A, then B, then A, then B, then A, so the array would end up being ['A','B','A','B','A']

Comment: So you want to prevent duplicates?

Comment: in the long run, i want to find the 'mode' of the array - in other words what is the value which occurs most? ['A','B','A','B','A'] A occurs the most amount of times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly your question, I created this fiddle with an approach to accomplish your task:

https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/hvr9ysq6/

html:

```
<div class="answer-A">
    <a href="#" data-value="A">
        <p style="color: white;">THOMAS EDISON</p>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="answer-B">
    <a href="#" data-value="B">
        <p style="color: white;">ALBERT EINSTEIN</p>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="answer-C">
    <a href="#" data-value="C">
        <p style="color: white;">NELSON MANDELA</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

js:

```
var finalAnswers = [];

$(document).ready(function () {

     $("a[data-value]").on("click", function(e) {
        var value = $(this).attr('data-value');
        finalAnswers.push(value);
       alert("Answers so far: " + finalAnswers.join(","));
        e.preventDefault();
     });

});
```

Comment: if i could 1 up you I would :)

Comment: you're welcome... you can accept this answer if solved your issue

Answer (score 0):

Use a selector that matches divs with class that start with `answer` and their anchor children

```
div[class^="answer-"] a
```

Iterate through these elements and get their value attribute. Like this:

```
var finalAnswers = [''];

$(document).ready(function () {
     $('div[class^="answer-"] a').each(function(i,v){
            finalAnswers.push($(v).attr("value"));
     });
     console.log(finalAnswers);
});
```

Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/1gmn1w1b/

Comment: this is really close but it doesn't seem to be working :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is example for your comment about how you want to push the value that user click.

```
var finalAnswers = [];

$(".answer-A, .answer-B, answer-C").click(function(){

    var value = $(this).children("a").attr("value");
    finalAnswers.push(value)
});
```